# Using まで together with a negative connotation 帰らないつもりです in a sentence

Tags: grammar, formal-nouns

I am referring Minna no Nihongo 2, Chapter 31 Mondai section.

The sentence pair is:

> Q:夏休みに国へかえりますか。
>   A:いいえ、クリスマスまで帰らないつもりです。

It would be great if you can tell me why the answer is 帰らないつもりです instead of 帰るつもりです? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

- 帰らないつもりです - I do not have the intention of returning.
- 帰るつもりです - I have the intention of returning.

The conversation goes:

> Q: Are you going to return home for the summer holidays?
>
> A: No, I don't plan to return until Christmas.  (hence the use of negative)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers. What if the speaker wants to convey the idea that he plans to return in Christmas (without the use of negative)? How to determine when to use negative?

Comment: Speaker's choice. Like in English you could say "No, but I will return home at Christmas" or "I won't return home until Christmas".